# Ng-select multiple="true"with checkbox (blur) event fired when I click on checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, blur

I was trying to implement (blur) with ng-select multiple with checkboxes,so the everytime I change my model I will not be making  api calls .API calls will be made only when ng-select is out of focus. Api will be called on (blur) . But when I click on checkbox which is defined inside ng-select only using ng-template it is triggering the blur event. I want to emit only on blur.

```
<div  style="width: 100%"  tabindex="0" >

                             <ng-select #mySelect  class="custom" [style]="{'height':'10px', 'width':'100%','border':'2px'}"

                                [items]="lookup.investorKnowledgeSource.asArray"
                                [multiple]="true"
                                [closeOnSelect]="false"
                                [(ngModel)]="it.source"
                                 placeholder="Select Source Of Knowledge Product"
                                [clearable]="false"
                                (ngModelChange)="onChangeKnowledgeSource($event,it)"
                                (blur)="change.emit()"

                               >
                           <ng-template   ng-multi-label-tmp >
                              <span><b>({{it.source.length}})Selected</b></span>
                          </ng-template>

                            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
                                <input id="item-{{index}}" type="checkbox"  [ngModel]="item$.selected"  [disabled]="item.disabled"/> {{item.label}}
                            </ng-template>
                          </ng-select>

                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blur event triggers only at the drop down level - only if you leave the drop down focus the blur event will be triggered it is not specific to the model change

You can add change event that might work or else use debounce from rxjs to trigger the api calls you can specify the api call after some amount of time

Comment: Checkbox is inside ng-select only .So I presume clicking on it will not be considered focusing out of ng-select . But still on click on checkboxes blur event is fired.

Comment: Try with close event then - it will fire when ever the drop down closed - if not try adding your data asynchronously where you can fire a event when the scroll happens